# Javascript string.split() fails on strings retrieved from textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split a string on newline which seems to work for strings that I declare within javascript, but it fails on strings that I'm retrieving from an html textbox. The idea is that this string splitting event should be triggered upon pasting something into a textbox.

I have no idea why this is only working on hard coded strings. Please have a look at the JSFiddle

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" name="test">
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').bind('paste', null, function(e){
    $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        var columns = $this.val().split(/\r?\n/);
        console.log(typeof $this.val());
        console.log(columns);
        var newstring = "a\nb\r\nc";
        console.log(newstring.split(/\r?\n/));
    },0);
});
});
```

#### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/aoon86r1/

Comment: So you are saying, you want every `\n` to be on newline, right?

Comment: And how are you adding `\r\n` in textbox?

Comment: TextBox wont support newline characters, so when you paste any text all new line characters are getting removed.
Try using TextArea
https://jsfiddle.net/aoon86r1/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input type="text">` are always single-line, so any text you enter into it will have any line breaks removed. In other words, the issue is not with your script but with the format of the source of the text.

If you want a multi-line text box, use `<textarea></textarea>` instead

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense to me. The thing is, I do sort of want that a user can only input single line stuff. In the event were multi line input is pasted in the textbox, I want to split the input into multiple strings on the newlines and only the first string will stay in that textbox, the remaining strings will then be assigned to other textboxes that are automatically added. Does it still make sense to use textarea in this case? Are there other workarounds?

Comment: @jonas87 Yes, you'll need to use a textarea for that in order to retain the line breaks so that you can identify them. You can style it to look exactly like a regular single-line input field, including preventing the user from resizing it.

Answer (score 1):

An `input` field is single-line, meaning that any newline breaks are removed from it (or processed some other way). You should be using a `textarea` element instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').bind('paste', null, function(e) {
    $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
      var columns = $this.val().split(/\r?\n/);
      console.log(typeof $this.val());
      console.log(columns);
      var newstring = "a\nb\r\nc";
      console.log(newstring.split(/\r?\n/));
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="test"></textarea>
```